# how to represent method for finding LCM (least common multiple) in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

How can we draw the ladder method for LCM (least common multiple) in LaTeX, as shown in the figure below,

[image]

If possible it'd be nice to have different colours for different lines and numbers, as shown

[image]

**Note:** I'd prefer to stick to `amsmath` or `mathtools` if possible.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution that employs a two-column `array` environment. (LuaLaTeX is needed only for the calculation of the LCM as the product of the individual factors.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{colortbl} 

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{array}{@{}l|l@{}}
2 & 48,72,108\\ \cline{2-2} 
2 & 24,36,54\\  \cline{2-2}
3 & 12,18,27\\  \cline{2-2}
\arrayrulecolor{red}
\color{red}3 & 4,6,9\\ \cline{2-2}
\color{red}2 & 4,2,3\\ \cline{2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & 2,1,3
\end{array}
\]
The \textsc{lcm} of $48$, $72$, and $108$ is the product
$\verb|2*2*3*3*2*2*1*3|=\directlua{tex.sprint(2*2*3*3*2*2*1*3)}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: No LuaLaTeX? ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Happy New Year to you too!! :-)

Comment: Happy New Year!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - You made me do it: I added a LuaLaTeX angle...

Comment: Sighhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh....

Answer (score 4):

Most likely I do not understand your question correctly, but it seems to me that you want to color some elements of a table. If so, then you may start with this code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l|rrr}
   \rowcolor{red!40} 3  & 12 & 15 & 18\\
   \hline
   \rowcolor{blue!30} 2  & 4 & 5 & 6\\
   \hline
    &  2 & \textcolor{blue!70}{5} & 3
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To produce something along the lines of your second picture, you may try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
   \textcolor{red}{3}  & \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red}\vline}r}{12} & 15 & 18\\
   \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-4}
   \textcolor{red}{2} &    \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{red}\vline}r}{4} & 5 & 6\\
   \arrayrulecolor{red}\cline{2-4}
    &   2 & 5 & 3
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have edited the original post. Hope it is clear now. pls check the second image.